# how to get two-hop neighbors in spark-graphx?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

I've created a directed graph, using graphx.

```
#src->dest
a  -> b  34
a  -> c  23
b  -> e  10
c  -> d  12
d  -> c  12
c  -> d  11
```

I want to get all two hop neighbors like this:

```
a  -> e  44
a  -> d  34
```

My graph is very large, so I would like to do it elegantly and efficiently.
Does anyone have any advice on what will be the best way to do that over a graph instance?

Answer (score 2):

You can succinctly express this using GraphFrames library. First you have to include required package. For with Spark 2.0 and Scala 2.11 you can add

```
graphframes:graphframes:0.2.0-spark2.0-s_2.11
```

to `spark.jars.packages` in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` or pass it as `--packages` argument for `spark-submit`.

Next you should convert `Graph` to `GraphFrame`. You can use `fromGraphX` method:

```scala
import org.graphframes.GraphFrame
import org.apache.spark.graphx._

val nodes = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, "a"), (2L, "b"), (3L, "c"), (4L, "d"), (5L, "e")))

val edges = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   Edge(1L, 2L, 34), Edge(1L, 3L, 23), Edge(2L, 5L, 10),
   Edge(3L, 4L, 12), Edge(3L, 3L, 12), Edge(3L, 5L, 11)))

val graph = Graph(nodes, edges)

val graphFrame = GraphFrame.fromGraphX(graph)
```

`GraphFrame` provides find method which takes a pattern in a language similar to Cypher. Two-hops can be expressed as:

```scala
val pattern = "(x1) - [a] -> (x2); (x2) - [b] -> (x3)"
```

where `(_)` represents nodes, and `[_]` edges. You paths matching the pattern:

```scala
val paths = graphFrame.find(pattern)
```

and `select` fields:

```scala
paths.select($"x1.attr", $"x3.attr", $"a.attr" + $"b.attr").show()
```

Comment: Is there a way to get 2-hops neighbors without using GraphFrame library?